# Creating a view in LogDNA

Tags: logging

I'm experimenting with LogDNA for log management. I'm looking to define a number of views and I'd like to do so programatically. I can see an API for logging, but I can't find an API for defining views. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no API for programmatically managing views.